# Deleting a node in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I was implementing binary search tree and also inputting values in to the tree and traversing using inorder traversal. Every function of my class works except deletion, deletion does work at all. Moreover, I would appreciate if someone explains to me why we return values for deletion?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class  node {
public:
    int key;
    node* right;
    node* left;
    node(int val)
    {
        key = val;
        right = NULL;
        left = NULL;
    }
};

class BinarySearchTree{
public:
    node* root = NULL;
    node* insert(node* root, int val) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            return new node(val);}
        else if (val > root->key) {
            root->right =  insert(root->right, val);
        }
        else if (val < root->key) {
            root->left = insert(root->left, val);
        }
        return root;}
    void inorder(node* root) {
        if (root == NULL)
            return;
        inorder(root->left);
        cout << "our node is that " << root->key << endl;
        inorder(root->right);
    }
    int minimumm(node* root) {
        node* current = root;
        while (current->left != NULL) {
            current = current->left;
        }
        return (current->key);
    }
    node* deletenode(node* root, int val) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            return root;
        }
        else if (val > root->key) {
            deletenode(root->right, val);
        }
        else if (val < root->key) {
            deletenode(root->left, val);}
        else {
            if (root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL) {
                delete(root);
                return NULL;
            }
            else if (root->right == NULL) {
                node* temp = root->left;
                delete(root);
                return temp;
            }
            else if (root->left == NULL) {
                node* temp = root->right;
                delete(root);
                return temp;
            }
            else {  
                int temp = minimumm(root->right);
                deletenode(root->right, temp);
                return root;
            }
        }
    }

};

int main() {
    BinarySearchTree bst;
    bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 100);
    bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 19);
    bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 47);
    bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 3);
    bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 111);
    bst.root = bst.insert(bst.root, 78);
    bst.inorder(bst.root);
    bst.root = bst.deletenode(bst.root, 78);
    bst.root = bst.deletenode(bst.root, 71);
    bst.inorder(bst.root);
}
```

I tried to delete 78 and 71 using deletion class but it didn't work at all

Comment: You definitely messed with tags. I'm removing all specific ones - please add back one (one!) related if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for "c++ delete node binary tree"?  There are already a plethora of examples and questions about binary trees.  We don't need more.  Remember, always search first.

Comment: You aren't setting `root->`'s `right/left` according to the return value.

Comment: After you search, use a debugger and pen and paper.  As you step through your code with the debugger, draw the nodes and links on the paper.

Comment: So if you find a node with the value to delete and this node has 2 children, you just delete some other node instead???